# how do you handle a case when in a table you got a foreign key that cannot be null?

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have a case where I have a linq2sql dbml with 2 table in it

let simplify this by:

```
Table1
id int not null
fkid int not null (to table2.id)
```

and

```
Table2
id int not null
v1 bit not null
```

in the generated dbml, fkid is not the type nullable and by default it's value is 0

but in table2, I don't have an id 0

when i'm trying to insert a new record without touching fkid field, I'm getting an SQL insert error saying: 0 doesn't exist into table2

thing is I want to make to make my check fully generic so I cannot just do something like:

if column doesn't allow null check if value is 0 and if it's the case throw a custom error

I would like to do something like: if column is null then throw "my custom error"

how would you implement that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since I'm using t4 template, I changed the line 80 in L2ST4.ttinclude from

```
if (type.IsValueType && canBeNull)
```

to

```
if (type.IsValueType)
```

so it ALWAYS set nullable type everywhere in the generated file

Comment: I just moved this from my question so I can give it a green check in 2 days, if there is no better answer